Upgrading from Lunar (23.04) to Noble (24.04 LTS)
I have a bunch of deployments stuck on 23.04 that I would like to upgrade to 24.04 LTS, and a couple of weeks ago I was successfully able to do so, not today.
The do-release-upgrade tool tried to upgrade directly to 24.04 and exits with failure that Lunar is not a supported upgrade path. So I dug around on the internet and found a reference to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and the UpgradeTool. I downloaded this for Mantic and was able to successfully upgrade some of my 23.04 instances to 23.10 and from there using the normal do-release-upgrade to get to 24.04.
However, when I today tried to upgrade the rest of my servers, I was unable to download the Mantic UpgradeTool as its now missing from archive.ubuntu.com. Its available from old-releases.ubuntu.com, however, so I downloaded it from there. But when executing it, I get the below output. It's complaining about not finding ubuntu-minimal.
Content of current Lunar sources.list (apt working good)
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security main restricted universe multiverse

Output of Mantic UpgradeTool:
bash
sudo ./mantic;
can't load DistUpgradeViewGtk3 (Namespace Vte not available)
can't load DistUpgradeViewKDE (No module named 'PyQt4')

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Hit https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt lunar-pgdg InRelease
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool
or your package manager.

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt lunar-pgdg InRelease
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

Invalid package information

After updating your package information, the essential package
'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of
excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list
for the current list of configured software sources.
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade
again later.


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

Is it a mistake that Mantic has been removed from archive.ubuntu.com(?) as meta-release content is still pointing to archive.ubuntu.com for Mantic and not old-releases?
Any suggestion for how I can get this working?
I know I should have upgraded earlier or stuck to LTS release but not helpful right now. I have huge databases deployed that I would really not like to have to restore on a fresh 24.04.

Our ability to help you greatly reduces as you've left it too late... Your system is currently lunar so we need to look up mantic (23.10) packages where details are no longer available; unless we have a nearby system available that is fully-updated.  For an easy upgrade path you had six months after 23.04 reached EOL before the next release goes EOL and it gets harder.. In future I suggest planning your release-upgrade and don't forget the 23.04 easily tells you when EOL is reached (2023-April + 9 months); and upgrade path closes 6 months later (unless next release is LTS)

You likely already have this, but https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Based on comments and my own findings I guess the only outcome is to re-deploy servers on a fresh 24.04 LTS :(
I tried every trick I could find to no avail.

The annoying thing to add is that my mentioned workaround worked great until 23.10 was removed from archive while 23.04 is still there. How come 23.10 specifically was removed? 23.04 isn't an LTS release either and 23.10 is the path to upgrade to 24.04?

Ubuntu 23.10 is EOL and as EOL announcements said (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/) "No more package updates will be accepted to 23.10, and it will be archived to old-releases.ubuntu.com in the coming weeks."   No specific date for drop or move is given, except it's AFTER EOL.  Upgrades from 23.10 to 24.04 will be open until AFTER 24.04 or noble reaches EOL which is years away due to LTS status of noble. Archives get moved once all work has completed on them & no more changes are in queues for build etc.

I believe that you need to change your /etc/apt/sources.list entries to point to old-releases.ubuntu.com instead of archive.ubuntu.com before running the upgrader.
When I did this today, I also changed line 180 in DistUpgradeController.py to read
self.default_source_uri = "http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"

and line 45 in DistUpgradeFetcherCore.py to read
DEFAULT_MIRROR = "http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"

I don't know if those .py changes were necessary. When running the updater it will give an error that no mirror was found, and then give the option to just change lunar to mantic in the sources.list. Accept that suggestion and continue
It's also possible that this wouldn't have worked until lunar was also moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com, as it recently was.
